# @Qualifier annotation not working

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I am trying DI with autowiring and I came across @Qualifier annotation annd tried the following code:

Car.java

```
package beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
//import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Car {  

@Autowired
@Qualifier("e1")

private Engine engine;
// no need to have setter or constructor

public void showData(){
    System.out.println("Engine Model Year : "+engine.getModelyear());
}

}
```

Engine.java

```
package beans;

public class Engine {
private String modelyear;

public void setModelyear(String modelyear) {
    this.modelyear = modelyear;
}

public String getModelyear() {
    return modelyear;
}

}
```

Spring.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<!-- activate autowire annotation -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
 <property name="modelyear" value="2017"/>
</bean>

<bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
 <property name="modelyear" value="2018"/>
</bean>

<bean id="c" class="beans.Car">

</bean>

</beans>
```

Main.java

```
package MainClass;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Car;

public class AutoAnno_Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
         Car c=(Car)ap.getBean("c");
            c.showData();
    }
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Engine' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: e1,e2
```

what's wrong in this I think the syntax is correct is there any problem with version
I am using **eclipse Oxygen**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `<context:annotation-config />` in your spring.xml. Certain spring annotations are not activated unless this is added. In your case, spring is not reading the @Qualifier annotation without the `<context:annotation-config />`.

I have tested by adding this and it seems to work.

**Update**:
Your spring xml needs to have the spring schema for that to detect `<context:annotation-config>`. Your final xml looks like this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!-- activate autowire annotation -->

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelyear" value="2017"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelyear" value="2018"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="c" class="beans.Car">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: It's not working instead showing more errors like Element type "context:annotation-config" must be declared.

Comment: You need to add xml schema as well. I will edit the answer.

Comment: that worked for me thanks..could you please explain me what you just did and what that schema is...??

Comment: Those are xml namespaces. You should read about them. You specify a schema, meaning what kind of tags you can use in the xml and how they are supposed to be interpreted. In this case, I added a spring schema. If this solution worked for you, can you accept the answer and upvote it?

Comment: what is the location of this schema in spring..??

Comment: What do you mean location?